# Arrays "double array[var];"

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, g++, double

I have given a task that goes like this: The array S[j] ( =0,…,7) has at least one zero element. Write a program to calculate the sum of the elements of this array up to the first element whose value is zero.

Array must be double.

I have tried this. But I am getting 0;

```
/* S[j] = (  =0,…,7) massivda  bittagina bo‘lsa  ham nolga teng elementi  mavjud. 
 Ushbu massivning qiymati nolga teng bo‘lgan birinchi elementgacha bo‘lgan 
 elementlarning yig‘indisini hisoblash dasturini tuzing. Boshlang‘ich 
 ma’lumotlar: 1, 17, 2, 4, -5, 0, 7, 8. */
 
 #include <iostream>
 
 using namespace std;
 
 int main()
 {
    int j;
    cout << "j:"; cin >>j;
    
    double S[j] = {};
    int P;
    
    for (int i = 0; i >= j-1; i++)
    {
        cout << "S[" << i << "]:"; cin >> S[i];
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i >= j; i++)
    {
        if (S[i] == 0) break;
        else P += S[i];
    }
    
    cout << P;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: you missed to initialize `P` and your code has undefined behavior

Comment: moreover `double S[j] = {};` is not standard C++

Comment: `double S[j] = {};` is a VLA and not part of standard C++.  adding `-pedantic-errors` will stop the code from compiling.

Comment: you do not actually need an array to sum up numbers form input until a `0` is entered

Comment: `double S[j] = {};`, where `j` is a variable, is not valid in standard C++.  g++ supports it as a non-standard extension.   Use something like `std::vector` instead.    Your first loop body never executes, since `i` is intialised to zero and (unless `j` is `1` or less) `i >= j-1`  is always `false`.   Similarly, the second loop body will never execute unless `j` is `0` or less.

Comment: you get `0` because this loop `for (int i = 0; i >= j-1; i++)` is wrong. It has 0 iterations.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @JaMiT they try to sum up all elements until they reach the element with value `0`.

Comment: do you mean while

Comment: @tukhsanov `if (S[i] == 0) break;` -- I hate to tell you this, but this may not ever be equal to 0, even if the hand calculation gives a result of 0.  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).  Even if you fix all of the issues mentioned above, that is the one glaring, huge issue you failed to address, and that is the issue of floating point calculations not always giving you exact answers.  The best you can do is to check if the value is "close to 0", and there are many links on SO that covers this topic.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got you

Comment: frankly, there is so much wrong in this code that you better start from scratch. And this time, do not write it all at once, but start simple. Write a loop that reads input into a `std::vector<double>` and make sure this works. Only when you are absolutely certain that this is ok, add more. To check you can print the elements of the vector, or even better use a debugger. In your code already taking input is broken

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I am a new learner. My teacher gave me this task and told that it has to be an array not a vector.

Comment: I see I have a lot of bugs/problems with my code. But thank you everybody for your attention.

Comment: you cannot determine the size of an array at runtime. Arrays have fixed size. You can read more about `std::vector` and when your teacher complains you can explain them that the requirements of the task are such that you need an array with dynamic size and the best solution for this is `std::vector`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: There are two ways in which "floating-point math looks broken" occurs, representation error on inputs and rounding error in computations.  Neither apply here (the representation error doesn't apply because `0.0` is exactly representable, and there is no computation done, the `== 0.0` check is done directly on an input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems.

Errors are:

- native arrays are difficult to manage and VLAs are forbidden. Prefer the use of some standard container (here `vector`);
- `P` is not initialized;
- loop control is wrong, you have to test a "while" condition, while the index is less than the size (`i < j` and not `i >= j-1`).

Recommandations are:

- don't start variable identifiers with uppercases, prefer lowercases (highly recommended);
- prefer the use of significant names, (`sum` preferable to `P`, `array` to `S`);
- if possible organize the code such that a computation is made by instructions close together (initialaze/declare `sum` just before the computation of it);
- prefer significant messages (`"How many doubles you need?"` is preferable to `"j:"`)
- prefer not to use `using namespace std`;
- `i`, `j`... are usually used for loop control, prefer `n` or `length` to reprensent a "size".

The code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

 int main() {
    using size_type = std::vector<double>::size_type;
    size_type n;
    std::cout << "How many doubles? ";
    std::cin >>n;

    // fill an "array" with values from the input
    std::vector<double> array;
    for (size_type i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double v;
        std::cout << "array[" << i << "]? ";
        std::cin >> v;
        array.push_back(v);
    }   
 
    // sum elements up to the one that is 0
    int sum=0;    
    for (size_type i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) break;
        else sum += array[i];
    }   
    std::cout << sum;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)` - signed-ness mismatch + type size mismatch on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Recommendation for future improvement: Test the stream state after all IO transactions. Right now someone could input "banana"  for `std::cin >>n;`, and the program will fail and keep trying to use `n` as if the user input a valid value. Exactly how it fails depends on the C++ Standard revision being used. In modern C++ bad input at `std::cin >>n;` will result in `n` being set to 0. In older versions the value of `n` is not clear.

Comment: @evg corrected size_type used for vector length.

Comment: I would declare a type alias: `using size_type = std::vector<double>::size_type;`, and then use it as the type for variable `n`, and also as the type for loop-control variable `i` in both loops.

Comment: @tbxfreeware done, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays like that

```
double S[j] = {};
```

where `j` is not a compile time constant expression are not a standard C++ feature.

If you want to deal with an array then you need to allocate it dynamically like

```
double *S = new int[j];
```

or

```
double *S = new int[j](); // to zero-initialize elements of the array
```

or

```
double *S = new int[j]{}; // to zero-initialize elements of the array
```

and in the end of the program you will need to free the array like

```
delete [] S;
```

or to use standard cintainer `std::vector<double>`.

The both for loops are skipped due to their conditions

```
for (int i = 0; i >= j-1; i++)

//..

for (int i = 0; i >= j; i++)
```

if `j` at least is greater than `1` because `0` can not be greater than any positive number.

The loops should look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < j and S[i] != 0; i++)
{
    P += S[i];
}
```

The variable `P` shall have type `double` and must be initialized by zero

```
double P = 0.0;
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks

Comment: @tukhsanov No at all. We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Comment: Let's not forget `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`, which works perfectly with either `new double[j]` (where in the world did `new int[]` come from???) or `std::make_unique<double[]>(j)` and does not require the programmer to remember to free the memory later.